# Fastest way to make image blink --> so fast that you didn't see it

Tags: javascript, image, blink

I'm looking for a way to make image blink so fast I cannot see it (and then avoid some screenshoting):

```
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    var i = true;

    setInterval(blink,10);
    
    function blink(){
        if(i){
            img.style.visibility="visible";
            i=false;
        }else{
            img.style.visibility="hidden";
            i=true;
        }
        
    }
```

But I still see the blink, and I think I could not lower than 10ms .
I was thinking initially that below 24 f/s I would not notice it, but it doesn't seems to be the case.

What could I change to make it faster ?
Is it even possible ?

**Final target is to avoid screen shooting .**

Comment: _"Make it blink, so fast that you cannot see it blink?"_ - Then why the blinking in the first place?

Comment: Sry I edit my message, it's to avoid some screenshoting

Comment: you are limited to relatively long pauses in computers - nothing you can absolutely control.

Comment: you can't avoid screen shotting.

Comment: unless you screenshot when it's visible?

Comment: I can just disable JavaScript to circumvent your "screenshot prevention"

Comment: Why disable javascript, just go to devtools, check the cached images, "save as".

Comment: Yes but most of people don't know about dev tool

Comment: Besides it should be noted, that it is hell for batteried devices like mobile phones and tablets.

Comment: The target was to avoid 90% of people to download the image, with this solution and other tricks

Comment: @Iyashi yes totaly agree ^^ but It's a proof of concept

Comment: Making the image blink is not gonna prevent people from screenshotting the image unless they're very very very unlucky.

Comment: Yes, @ibrahimmahrir , but it will add some difficulty to copy the picture, that' the target .
But yeah you are completely right

Comment: I imagine going to a website, that wants to show me some image, and it blinks every now and then for a frame. Afterwards, my bug report gets closed with "working as intended, it's screenshot protection". It would take some time to convince me that wasn't a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard refresh rate for monitors is [60Hz](https://insights.samsung.com/2020/01/16/how-do-refresh-rates-work-for-monitors/#:%7E:text=The%20desktop%20monitor%20standard%20is,on%2Dscreen%20visuals%20may%20be) - 60 times per second. This is a *hardware limitation* - even with perfect software timing, there's no way to display frames more frequently than that - and humans paying attention to a screen can easily see something that appears for 1/60th of a second.

Your only option is to have the image appear and disappear with every frame (which can be done more precisely than `setInterval` with `requestAnimationFrame` - but it'll still be visible to those watching closely).

```js
// Ensure browser is not busy
setTimeout(() => {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('blue');
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      document.body.classList.toggle('blue');
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

It's not possible for the monitor to display something for a low enough duration that it's not perceivable.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation :D

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution I can think of is to CSS [animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations) the [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) property. [The opacity property is animated on the GPU. This means less load on the CPU and the mainthread.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/)

```css
#box {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
background: red;
animation: 1ms steps(2, jump-none) 0s infinite running blink;

}

@keyframes blink {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Secret Image</div>
```